# How to input surround sound to my PC from an external source

Tags: windows-10, audio, surround-sound

Ok, here's the deal. I have looked online quite a bit, and I can't find anywhere that actually says how to do this. Just that you shouldn't (for reasons that do not apply to me, more on that below). You can skip straight to my question at the bottom, however clarifications/explanations/etc. will be divided up before it, so here goes.

### **My Setup**

I am currently using a G933 headset (soon to be G935) in stereo mode, with Dolby Atmos for Headphones enabled on my PC. This is fully compatible with Dolby Atmos, 7.1, 5.1, etc. Please note, I am *not* using *any* kind of surround sound *speakers*. The surround sound is virtualized for a stereo headset. Windows 10.

### **What Research I've Done**

I've done quite a bit of Googling on the situation, but my Google-fu has failed me. Everything I've come up with has said not to do this because you need amplifiers, etc. to power the speakers. I don't need that as I am using a virtualized headset.

### **My Audio Sources**

The sources of my surround sound will be mostly consoles like the PS4, Xbox One, Wii U, etc. as well as things like Amazone Fire TV. I will be using an HDMI Matrix with six inputs and two outputs to hook them up to my monitor. Its sound outputs are through the output HDMI, an optical SPDIF output, and an AUX cable output.

### **What I've Tried**

I have tried using my Elgato capture card to receive the 5.1 surround sound from the Wii U via HDMI, but even if I could do it without capture software open, it only comes through with stereo (3/5 dings are heard on the audio test: left, right, and center).

### **My Question**

How can I get surround sound audio (including, but not limited to, 5.1/7.1/Dolby Atmos) from an HDMI cable (or any other cable) into my PC? I don't need my PC to be an AV Receiver in the "Home Theatre" sense (I'm not powering a bunch of speakers). I just need to be able to input the surround sound to my PC in such a way that Dolby Atmos for Headphones can receive it as surround sound and as such, output the surround sound virtually to my PC headset.

I tried to include everything I can think of, but if I should add more info let me know. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Looking at Elgato website, I found no audio capability specifications of their video capture devices. Maybe some of them support more than two audio channels, but maybe not.
There are many cheap USB audio adapters, able to capture 6 or 8 audio channels; they have 3 or 4 audio input jacks. Most probably, there are such adapters with HDMI input jacks.
To record multi-channel audio, you need multi-channel recording software. You didn't mention your OS; for Windows, you could try Wavosaur.

Comment: Ah yeah, went ahead and added the OS. The issue is I can't find any of these adapters. I've looked for HDMI USB AV Receivers, Optical equivalents, etc. I just wish there was a simple way to extract surround sound to a PC. Another problem I don't want to run into is latency because of software.

Comment: Looks like that there are no pure HDMI audio convertors, only full video/audio ones. Unfortunately, full converters are expensive, because video part costs 90-95%. I'm afraid your problem has no simple solution.

Comment: @EugeneMuzychenko I can also work with other audio cables if necessary, i.e. my Matrix has an output via optical. It's too bad Dolby doesn't just make an Atmos USB receiver to work with an existing PC setup.

Comment: Also I am good with a complicated solution too, as long as it works and doesn't cost a fortune.

Comment: You can try to search for the "hdmi audio extractor". Some of such devices can extract audio channels from HDMI to a compressed 5.1 stream on S/PDIF. But S/PDIF can handle more than two channels only in a compressed form.

Comment: @EugeneMuzychenko That is something I could look into, since one of them is a 7.1 as well, but my Matrix already acts as an extractor. It gets the audio from the HDMI and outputs it as 5.1 via S/PDIF. I'm trying to figure out how to get that into my PC for live playback. Appreciate the help.

Comment: There are many USB audio adapters (including cheap ones) that support S/PDIF inputs. But most of them support only two-channel uncompressed formats. So you need to pay attention to technical characteristics.